# React Invalid hook call while using chartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-chartjs

I attempted to add a chartJS line chart to my application and got 'Invalid Hook Call' errors. I figured I might be doing something wrong, so I started a fresh application and attempted to follow a tutorial. After following this VERY basic [youtube tutorial for using ChartJS in React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXuElLhCK8s), I get a blank page.
If I go to inspect->console. I see errors for 'Invalid Hook Call'.

[image]

I have checked both versions of react-native and react-dom; versions do not seem to be the issue. This is my output from `npm ls` for reference.

[image]

My `./App.js` code - its literally almost a copy of the tutorial . If i remove the `<Bar />` from the return at the bottom, application runs fine.  :

```
import './App.css';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS, 
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js'
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend);

function App() {

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    datasets: [],
  });

  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setChartData({
      labels: ["Greg", "Chuck", "Kevin", "Sam", "Seth"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Votes", 
          data: [50,1,1,0,1000],
          borderColor: "rgb(53, 162, 235)",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.3)",
        },
      ],
    })
    setChartOptions({
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: "top",
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Who does the most work?",
        },
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>BarChart</h2>
      <Bar options={chartOptions} data={chartData} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Does anyone see something I'm not as to why I could be getting this error?

Comment: I copied your code to a codesandbox with `chart.js` version 3.8.0 and it is working fine for me, I'm not sure how else to reproduce. Have you tried reinstalling `react-chartjs-2`

Comment: Thanks for the verification. That will have to be my next step, re-installing all the components. Curious if I have a bad install on node or react causing me issues.